# ASP.NET Resx Resource randomly giving null reference exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization, globalization

I was viewing the error log for a site I develop for, and a certain line in a page is giving a null reference exception every now and then, very randomly. For example of the randomness, it maybe will return null once or twice in every 100 hits.
Here is the line:

```
@Resources.Global.ThankYou
```

And here is the structure of the resources folder (The Resources folder is at the root of the web project folder):

[image]

The users I have spoken to with the error all seem to be on english operating systems, and all the errors in the log I checked have this similarity in their passed HTTP request attributes:

HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE:en-au

And most but not all users that experience the issue seem to be on an iphone or ipad (some android too).
To try and replicate the Issue I have pushed english-australian to the top of my language list and tested the exact same page, but it works fine - as it does for the other 98% of users, and picks up the default Global.resx ThankYou value which is in english.

Has anyone got any ideas to how some users could get the random null reference exception? I will be VERY grateful for any feedback!

Comment: That is very odd behavior. The only thing I would do differently, and can think of, is not call it `Global` since that is a keyword in C#. It is possible it is causing some confusion somewhere. This is just a long shot and I could be just talking garbage.

Comment: Hi @CodingYoshi, I had assumed that it would be OK being inside the resources namespace, however I am desperate so I will give it a shot of renaming it - thank you very much for your feedback!

Comment: You are right and it should be OK but I was desperate too and that is all I could think of ;)

Comment: What line is throwing the exception?

Comment: Hi @mjwills it is the line: Resources.Global.ThankYou

Answer (score 2):

If this helps anyone, it ended up being a misleading exception from ASP.NET. The error was actually occurring in the following lines where a property of the model was null in some instances. ASP.NET Incorrectly was stating it was on the Resource. Here is an example I was able to replicate:
[image]

The error was actually on the circled property 2 lines later, not on the line suggested by asp.net. I hope this helps!